# How do I solve from /r/ARG - "Ykt bavc..."

Tags: cipher

[image: encrypted message]

**It says some cryptic wording. I'm unsure how to proceed.**

Transcription:

```
Ykt bavc skjc htnqbcn ikpq bavc. Ykt bavc aj klqdkj bcnc.
Rkjqdjtc agkjc. Dq scqp itrb iknc odhhdrtgq ap wc lnkrcco. 
Pcjo aj coadg qk cjog1js aq lnkqkjiadg okq rb hkn qbc jcxq pqcl
hknwano.
```

Comment: I'd start with transcribing it and feeding it to a caesar-decryptor.

Comment: The important things to notice are: word lenghts look normal, there are repeated words, and there are never three of the same character in a row. Therefore it is very likely natural language encrypted with a simple substitution cipher, which means that one letter is always encrypted by replacing it with the same letter. Those are easy to solve by pen and paper: start by solving one word, and work from there.

Comment: Letter and letter-pair frequencies are useful hints. Transcribe the text and use [these tools](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/monogram-bigram-and-trigram-frequency-counts/), then compare with [typical Engish texts](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/letter-frequencies-various-languages/english-letter-frequencies/). C seems to be a good candidate for _e_. (And if that's true, YKT isn't _the_.)

Answer (score 1):

```
ABCDEFGIHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
AHEI??LMFNOP?RDSTCGU?VWXY?
```

Decoding with the substitution cipher shown above you get:

You have gone further than most have.
You have an option here.
Continue alone.
It gets much more difficult as we proceed.
send an email to endl1ng at protonmail dot ch for the next step forward.

Comment: This is a keyword cipher with 'AUROCHS' as the keyword.